# Extract substring address SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a table with column `Address` which is like `city. City_Name, citysector. CitySector, Street. Street_Name, StreetNumber. Street_Number`

```
EXAMPLE
Address
c. Paris, s. ParisDowntown, str. Rue Étienne Marcel, nr. 50
```

How can I substract 4 different columns like city, sector, street, streetNumber from Address column?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySql does not use T-SQL. It's SQL dialect is called MySql. I've removed the conflicting tags from your question. Please [edit] it to include relevant tags only.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, ok, sorry, I'll remember

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019

Comment: Is this what you asking ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to know, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a couple of replaces you can change your string format to json, and then use `openjson` to extract the values.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    [Address] nvarchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO @T ([Address]) VALUES 
('c. Paris, s. ParisDowntown, str. Rue Étienne Marcel, nr. 50');
```

The query:

```
SELECT City, CitySector, Street, Number
FROM @T
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('{"' + REPLACE(REPLACE([Address], ', ', '", "'), '. ', '":"') + '"}') 
WITH (
    City nvarchar(100) '$.c',
    CitySector nvarchar(100) '$.s',
    Street nvarchar(100) '$.str',
    Number int '$.nr'
) As vals
```

Results:

```
City    CitySector      Street              Number
Paris   ParisDowntown   Rue Étienne Marcel  50
```

Comment: It's a little bit harder than I expected, Is there a more simple way to do this? Anyway thanks a lot!